# [emulation] ← [emulator]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Any reason why we shouldn't make [emulator](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emulator) a synonym of [emulation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emulation)?

[Synonym proposal.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/emulation/synonyms)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason whatsoever.

Do it.